# C#-normalizing a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-ce

i have a table like this:
[image]

I have to normalise this as:
[image]

Will you please help me with the code..?
Thnks in advance..

Comment: What code? I don't see any...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Query:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp
GO

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    SomeColumn CHAR(1),
    [30-12-2013] INT,
    [31-12-2013] INT,
    [01-01-2014] INT
)

INSERT INTO #temp (SomeColumn, [30-12-2013], [31-12-2013], [01-01-2014])
VALUES 
    ('A', 540, 100, 246),
    ('B', 130, 90, 377)

SELECT *
FROM #temp
UNPIVOT (
    [Date] FOR Amount IN ([30-12-2013], [31-12-2013], [01-01-2014])
) unpvt
```

**Output:**

```
SomeColumn Date        Amount
---------- ----------- -----------
A          540         30-12-2013
A          100         31-12-2013
A          246         01-01-2014
B          130         30-12-2013
B          90          31-12-2013
B          377         01-01-2014
```

**Additional info:**

[Is UNPIVOT the best way for converting columns into rows?](http://blog.devart.com/is-unpivot-the-best-way-for-converting-columns-into-rows.html)

**Dynamic solution:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE temp
GO

CREATE TABLE temp (
    SomeColumn CHAR(1),
    [30-12-2013] INT,
    [31-12-2013] INT,
    [01-01-2014] INT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.temp (SomeColumn, [30-12-2013], [31-12-2013], [01-01-2014])
VALUES 
    ('A', 540, 100, 246),
    ('B', 130, 90, 377)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT *
FROM dbo.temp
UNPIVOT (
    [Date] FOR Amount IN (' + STUFF((
    SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.temp')
        AND name LIKE '__-__-____'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')
) unpvt'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.temp
UNPIVOT (
    [Date] FOR Amount IN ([30-12-2013], [31-12-2013], [01-01-2014])
) unpvt
```